# Can I reprogram Mouse-Keys?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I don't use the mouse a lot so I just use the Mouse Keys (Microsoft's nomenclature) when I need to click something. The problem is I can never remember whether I am in left-click or right-click mode. Would it be possible, for example, to get it to revert to left-click modeafter every right-click or middle-click?

Answer (score 1):

You can set commands for mouse keys with ccsm.

Open a terminal. (Ctrl+Alt+T)

To install ccsm type:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then type

```
ccsm
```

to start ccsm.

Click on Commands and type in a command. Enable the commands plugin.
Now click on Button bindings. There you can set your mouse buttons.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't read that you want to control your mouse with the keyboard :)

I hope this helped you,
Daniel

Comment: Mouse Keys is a way of controling the pointer with the keyboard. It can be turned on in gnome-keyboard-properties

Comment: Why didn't you add that as an answer and accept it? That would be better, since others could then see that the problem was solved.